# Добавление пары в вектор

Tags: c++

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<std::ifstream, int>> v;
    std::ifstream in;
    v.emplace_back(in, 42);
}
```

Почему код не компилируется? Как сделать правильно?

```
no matching function for call to 'std::pair<std::basic_ifstream<char>, int>::pair(std::basic_ifstream<char>&, int)'
```

Comment: у stream остутствует конструктор копирования - используйте перемещение

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch понял, спасибо

Comment: Или `unique_ptr`, или `shared_ptr`.

Comment: Я бы использовал указатель на `ifstream`.